# What's the differences between has_object_permission and has_permission?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-permissions

I am confused with the `BasePermission` in Django-rest-framework.

Here I defined a class: `IsAuthenticatedAndOwner`.

```
class IsAuthenticatedAndOwner(BasePermission):
    message = 'You must be the owner of this object.'
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        print('called')
        return False
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        # return obj.user == request.user
        return False
```

Using in `views.py`

```
class StudentUpdateAPIView(RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    serializer_class = StudentCreateUpdateSerializer
    queryset = Student.objects.all()
    lookup_field = 'pk'
    permissions_classes = [IsAuthenticatedAndOwner]
```

But it doesn't work at all. Everyone can pass the permission and update the data.

The `called` wasn't printed.

---

And I used to define this class: `IsNotAuthenticated`

```
class IsNotAuthenticated(BasePermission):
    message = 'You are already logged in.'
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return not request.user.is_authenticated()
```

It works well in the function

```
class UserCreateAPIView(CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = UserCreateSerializer
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    permission_classes = [IsNotAuthenticated]
```

So, what are the differences between the examples above, and function `has_object_permission` & `has_permission`?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Basically, the first code denies everything because `has_permission` return False.

`has_permission` is a check made before calling the `has_object_permission`. That means that you *need* to be allowed by `has_permission` before you get any chance to check the ownership test.

What you want is:

```
class IsAuthenticatedAndOwner(BasePermission):
    message = 'You must be the owner of this object.'
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return request.user and request.user.is_authenticated
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        return obj.user == request.user
```

This will also allow authenticated users to create new items or list them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.Maybe my question is not clear.At first, my codes was just like yours.But it didn't work and everyone could pass the permission.Then i update the function by`return False`. And it still pass everyone.

Comment: So what is the difference? Why do we need 2 functions as opposed to only one?

Comment: DRF documentation explains it. `has_permission` is a "generic" permission check to see whether or not the request meet some criteria. `has_object_permission` is more specific and linked to a specific instance.

Answer (score 74):

We have following two permission methods on `BasePermission` class:

- `def has_permission(self, request, view)`
- `def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj)`

Those two different methods are **called for restricting unauthorized users** for data insertion and manipulation.

`has_permission` is called on all HTTP requests whereas, `has_object_permission` is called from DRF's method `def get_object(self)`. Hence, `has_object_permission` method is available for `GET`, `PUT`, `DELETE`, not for `POST` request.

**In summary:**

- `permission_classes` are looped over the defined list.
- `has_object_permission` method is called after `has_permission` method returns value `True` except in POST method (in `POST` method only `has_permission` is executed).
- When a `False` value is returned from the `permission_classes` method, the request gets no permission and will not loop more, otherwise, it checks all permissions on looping.
- `has_permission` method will be called on all (`GET`, `POST`, `PUT`, `DELETE`) `HTTP` request.
- `has_object_permission` method will not be called on `HTTP POST` request, hence we need to restrict it from `has_permission` method.

Comment: Very nice answer. But where did you get all this information? Is there a link to it in the documentation? If there is, it would be nice to add it to the answer itself.

Comment: @PhilippeFanaro documention here: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#object-level-permissions

Comment: @luistm here https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#custom-permissions

Comment: In my case `has_object_permission` is not being called even though `has_permission` returns True and the method is HTTP GET

Answer (score 3):

`has_permission()` is a method on the BasePermission class that is used to check if the user has permission to perform a certain action on the entire model. For example, you might use it to check if a user has permission to view a list of all objects of a certain model.

`has_object_permission()` is a method on the BasePermission class that is used to check if the user has permission to perform a certain action on a specific instance of the model. For example, you might use it to check if a user has permission to view, update or delete a specific object of a certain model.

For example, you might have a Book model and a User model in your application. You could use `has_permission()` to check if a user has permission to view a list of all books, while you use `has_object_permission()` to check if a user has permission to view, update or delete a specific book.

```
class IsBookOwnerOrAdmin(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
       # Check if the user is authenticated
       if not request.user.is_authenticated:
          return False
       # Allow access for superusers
       if request.user.is_superuser:
           return True
       # Allow access if the user is the owner of the book
       if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
           return True
       return False

   def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
       # Allow access for superusers
       if request.user.is_superuser:
           return True
       # Allow access if the user is the owner of the book
       return obj.owner == request.user
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this can help:

```
class IsAuthorOrReadOnly(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        # Read-only permissions are allowed for any request
        if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
            return True
        # Write permissions are only allowed to the author of a post
        return obj.user == request.user
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, you are not adding your custom permission to the class as an argument.

This is your code:

```
class StudentUpdateAPIView(RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    serializer_class = StudentCreateUpdateSerializer
    queryset = Student.objects.all()
    lookup_field = 'pk'
    permissions_classes = [IsAuthenticatedAndOwner]
```

But it should be:

```
class StudentUpdateAPIView(RetrieveUpdateAPIView, IsAuthenticatedAndOwner):
    serializer_class = StudentCreateUpdateSerializer
    queryset = Student.objects.all()
    lookup_field = 'pk'
    permissions_classes = [IsAuthenticatedAndOwner]
```

Note the custom permission `IsAuthenticatedAndOwner` as an argument in the class header.

PS: I hope this helps, I am a beginner in DRF but this is one of the things I just learned.