# Django Rest Framework Custom Permission not taking effect

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

I have a permissions.py file that holds a custom permission called CanViewUserRecord. I have assigned this to a viewset called UserRecordView. The permission isn't working though, whenever I call the endpoint attached to the viewset all of the data from the database is returned. Here is the custom permission code:

```
from accounts.models import Staff

class CanViewUserRecord(permissions.BasePermission):

    edit_methods = ("PUT", "PATCH")

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
            if obj.account_type == "staff":
                # If user is the manager of staff
                if obj.staff.manager == request.user.id:
                    return True
                # If the user is the owner
                if obj == request.user:
                    return True
                # Allow admins to access
                if request.user.account_type == "admin":
                    return True
                return False

            elif obj.account_type == "manager":
                # If the user is the owner
                if obj == request.user:
                    return True
                # Allow Admins to access
                if request.user.account_type == "admin":
                    return True
                return False

            elif obj.account_type == "admin":
                # If the user is the owner
                if obj == request.user:
                    return True
                # Allow Admins to access
                if request.user.account_type == "admin":
                    return True
                return False
            else:
                return False
        elif request.method in self.edit_methods:
            if obj.account_type == "staff":
                if (
                    request.user.account_type == "manager"
                    or request.user.account_type == "admin"
                ):
                    return True

                else:
                    return False
            elif obj.account_type == "manager":
                return True
            else:
                return False

        return False
```

The idea is to limit what users can see depending on the account_type of the user assigned to the token supplied to the API endpoint. Here is my viewset code:

```
class UserRecordView(views.APIView):
    """
    API View to create or get a list of all the registered
    users. GET request returns the registered users whereas
    a POST request allows to create a new user.
    """

    permission_classes = [CanViewUserRecord, permissions.IsAuthenticated]

    def get(self, format=None):
        users = Account.objects.all()
        serializer = AccountSerializer(users, many=True)
        return response.Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = AccountSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=ValueError):
            serializer.save()
            return response.Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return response.Response(
            {
                "error": True,
                "error_msg": serializer.error_messages,
            },
            status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,
        )
```

So if I make a request with a token that is assigned to a user who is a "manager" I don't want them to be able to see records for a user who has the account_type "admin". However, I did a test where the permission just returned False and nothing else and the API request still returns data even when the permission is set to False. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong? Here's the model for field reference:

```
class Account(auth_models.AbstractBaseUser):

    username = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True, primary_key=True)

    ACCOUNT_TYPE_CHOICES = (
        ("manager", "Manager"),
        ("staff", "Staff"),
        ("admin", "Admin"),
    )

    account_type = models.CharField(
        choices=ACCOUNT_TYPE_CHOICES,
        default="staff",
        blank=False,
        null=False,
        max_length=10,
    )
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="Date Joined", 
              auto_now_add=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = "username"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ["account_type"]

    objects = AccountManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True

class Staff(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(null=False, blank=False)
    manager = models.ForeignKey(Manager, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    employment_start_date = models.DateField(null=False, blank=True)
    employment_end_date = models.DateField(blank=True)
    role = models.ForeignKey(
        Role, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="assigned_staff"
    )

    REQUIRED_FIELDS = [
        "user",
        "first_name",
        "last_name",
        "date_of_birth",
        "manager",
        "employment_start_date",
        "role",
    ]
```

EDIT: I've added the has_permission function into the permission as suggested by JPG in the comments. The data that is being returned is still incorrect and is giving me to access it shouldn't have permission to. Here is the updated code:

```
class CanViewUserRecord(permissions.BasePermission):

    edit_methods = ("PUT", "PATCH")
    message = None

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            return True

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
            if obj.account_type == "employee":
                # If user is the employer
                if obj.employee.employer == request.user.id:
                    return True
                # If the user is the owner
                if obj == request.user:
                    return True
                # Allow Jool Admins to access
                if request.user.account_type == "jool-admin":
                    return True
                self.message = "Requestor does not have access to this employee record"
                return False

            elif obj.account_type == "provider":
                # If the user is the owner
                if obj == request.user:
                    return True
                # Allow Jool Admins to access
                if request.user.account_type == "jool-admin":
                    return True
                self.message = "Requestor cannot view provider records"

                return False

            elif obj.account_type == "jool-admin":
                # If the user is the owner
                if obj == request.user:
                    return True
                # Allow Jool Admins to access
                if request.user.account_type == "jool-admin":
                    return True
                self.message = "Requestor cannot view admin records"
                return False
            else:
                return False
        elif request.method in self.edit_methods:
            if obj.account_type == "employee":
                if (
                    request.user.account_type == "provider"
                    or request.user.account_type == "jool-admin"
                ):
                    return True

                else:
                    return False
            elif obj.account_type == "provider":
                return True
            else:
                return False

        return False
```

Comment: The ***`has_permission(...)`*** method must return ***`True`*** in order to make call to the `has_object_permission(...)` methodf

Comment: so do I have to override the has_permission() function in the permission class?

Comment: @JPG still getting the issue, I have updated the code in the question

Comment: what is the error message? Try placing IsAuthenticated before your custom permission

Comment: So what I'm trying to do is for each item in the GET response, I want to limit which user records that the person requesting from the API can see depending on their account type

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for
[whats-the-differences-between-has-object-permission-and-has-permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43064417/whats-the-differences-between-has-object-permission-and-has-permission)

```
has_object_permission(...)
```

call when you call `get_object()` so you have to override the `has_permission(...)` instead.
As I see:

```
def has_permission(self, request, view):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return True
```

this always allow user already login to pass CanViewUserRecord

Comment: So what I'm trying to do is for each item in the GET response, I want to limit which user records that the person requesting from the API can see depending on their account type

Comment: I think you can use ListApiView and then override the get_queryset(..) to limit what users can see based on their account type instead of writing permission.

Comment: But with ListAPIView do I have access to the request and the object?